# Adding Google OAuth2 Authentication to customized OWIN middleware

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, google-oauth, owin

So far, I've been using a customized OWIN middleware for my WEB API OAuth2 authentication. This worked fine for internal users, but did not support external accounts such as Facebook, or Google.

So, I decided to try and add that feature.

I have created a provider for the Google Authentication pipeline:

```
public class GoogleAuthProvider : IGoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider {

     public void ApplyRedirect(GoogleOAuth2ApplyRedirectContext context) {
         context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
     }

     public Task Authenticated(GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext context) {
         /* I'm creating a new claim so I can retrieve the access token later on from the context */
         Claim authClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String);
         context.Identity.AddClaim(authClaim);

         return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
     }

     public Task ReturnEndpoint(GoogleOAuth2ReturnEndpointContext context) {
         return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
     }
}
```

I am configurating my Google Authentication pipeline as follows:

```
private GoogleAuth2AuthenticationOptions ConfigureGoogle() { 
     return new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() {
          ClientId = "xxx",
          ClientSecret = "xxx",
          Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
     }
}
```

I'm then injecting it into my application:

```
GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatioOptions googleConfig = ConfigureGoogle();
application.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleConfig);
```

Before external logins, I've been using OAuth Bearer authentication for local accounts. I had configured an Authorization Server:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions serverConfig = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {
     AllowInsecureHttp = !secure,
     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(tokenEndpoint),
     AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = accessTokenExpiration,
     Provider = authorizationProvider, // (OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)
     RefreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider // (IAuthenticationTokenProvider)
}
application.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverConfig);
```

I would like to keep my access token endpoint, and not create an additional one for handling external logins. I have the configured providers, how can I use them on my **authorization server**?.

My authorization server uses a `grant_type = password`, which expects an username and a password. Is there a grant type for external accounts **that do not have passwords** on my system?